# Using MiniProfiler in a Load Balanced Web Server Environment

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

Running mini profiler on a single web server is a no brainer, it just works, however when I run behind BIG-IP with an IP based pool I get 404s when requesting this resource "results/mini-profiler-resources".

[image: Chrome developer tools]

The profiler does show results, but they seem to be very random and mixed with events that have taken place in other views/pages. I'm hoping someone might have experience with this and can point me in the right direction.

Thank you,
Stephen

Relevant code

Packages

```
<package id="MiniProfiler" version="3.0.10" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="MiniProfiler.MVC4" version="3.0.10" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Configuration

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>
<handlers>
  <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="2097151" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

Global

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (EnableProfiler)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
    }
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if (EnableProfiler)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop();                
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your bigip configured for sticky load balancing? Or round-robin? For round-robin, you probably need to provide a custom storage provider (only about 2 methods to implement)

Comment: @MarcGravell What methods?, as our architecture also prohibits a dmz machine from talking directly to a db, instead it has to go through an application server. Anyways, i'd like to also store the dmz results in the db along with the memory provider.

Comment: I'm not at a PC right now, but basically there's an interface and config setting for "where to store stuff" that is really simple to implement : essentially "get stuff" and "set stuff". I can look it up when at a PC. How you implement it is up to you. In a round-robin scenario you would need this, because the default is in-memory.

Comment: The interface in question is [`IStorage`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/IStorage.cs). It and the implementations provided out of the box are [located here](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage). You can change the storage that you are using by setting `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage`. **Update:** see my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24053413/51) based on this comment.

Comment: @MarcGravell Ya, I had the balancer set to sticky with cookie and that fixed everything. I will also have to code an IStorage implementation if I want this stuff persisted beyond memory as the web front ends don't have access to a database, but that for another day.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your issues will be solved by implementing a custom storage provider or by using one of the alternatives provided other than the default HttpRuntimeCacheStorage.

The main built-in alternative to use is [SqlServerStorage](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/SqlServerStorage.cs). If you would like to use a different db for storage, then inherit from [DatabaseStorageBase](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/DatabaseStorageBase.cs) and implement the functions per your needs.

If you are interested in creating your own custom storage interface, you will need to implement [`IStorage`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/IStorage.cs). Here you can dictate how to both store and retrieve profiler records (and you can choose a medium that will work with you load-balanced web server environment).

You can change the storage that you are using by setting `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage` to your chosen storage provider.